# Is there any way on Minecraft java, to go from local network to a different one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open Minecraft and go into multiplayer every single time I must go into direct connection and I have horrible memory so if anyone knows how to make servers show up instead of it always saying, "scanning for games on your local network..." that would be amazing!!!

Answer (score 1):

## The "Add Server" button is what you're looking for!

Click the button (shown below) to open up the "Edit Server Info" prompt. From there, you can provide the following information;

- **Server Name:** An arbitrary name that you alone use to identify what server is what. This has no impact on you joining, and is only there to help you remember what server goes where. For example, you could give Hypixel the server name "pee", and it would work just as well as naming it "Hypixel".
- **Server Address:** This is the domain/IP of the server you want to save (e.g. Hypixel's is mc.hypixel.net). This is case-sensitive, but doesn't require anything like "https://" in it.
- **Server Resource Packs:** Some servers, like Hypixel, have custom resource packs to provide things like specially modeled items or paintings in their games. This button should usually be kept to "Prompt" by default, but if you trust the server you're connecting to, you can set it to "Enabled"; conversely, you can also disable it outright by setting it to "Disabled", preventing it from downloading and setting the resource pack.

  - **Note:** Regardless of what this setting is set to, resource packs set by the server are automatically disabled and removed when you leave them; this *does* include subsections of servers (like minigames).

[image: A screen snippet of a Minecraft game, showcasing the Direct Connection, Add Server, Refresh, and Back buttons.]